# get values from prepared statement in java

Tags: java, sql

i need some help with that prepared statement. i want in conversion map to have values  like sum from previous 2 maps. give me some help please

```
 statement = connection.prepareStatement("select count(*) as count,b.bankid,status from................... between ? and ? group by status,bankid order by bankid");
                statement.setInt(1, PaymentType.CONVERSION);
                statement.setTimestamp(2, dateFrom);
                statement.setTimestamp(3, dateTo);
                rs = statement.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int status = rs.getInt("status");
                    String bankid =rs.getString("bankid");

                    if (status == 1) {
                        suc.put(bankid, rs.getInt("count"));
                    }else {
                        fail.put(bankid, rs.getInt("count"));
                    }
                    conv.put(bankid, success.get("count") + failed.get("count"));
```

Comment: What's wrong with that code ?

Comment: in the map conversion i should have sum from  success+failed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong key for your `success` and `failed` maps.

`success.get("count") + failed.get("count")`

should be

`success.get(bankid) + failed.get(bankid)`

You should also protect against a null being returned from the `get` from the `success` or `failed` map, in case those maps don't have an entry for the bankid at the time you evaluate that expression.

For example:

```
public Integer safeGet(Map<String, Integer> map, String key) {
  if (map == null || key == null || !map.containsKey(key)) {
    return Integer.valueOf(0);
  }
  return map.get(key);
}
```

Then use:

```
conversion.put(bankid, safeGet(success, bankid) + safeGet(failed, bankid));
```

Comment: how to protect against a null being returned from the get?